# The checksum verification of the file failed (downloaded from https://repo.magento.com/archives/vertex/module-tax/vertex-module-tax-3.0.0.0.zip)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Has anyone faced up an issue during magento installation with composer?

> - Installing vertex/module-tax (3.0.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>   **[UnexpectedValueException]   The checksum verification of the file
>     failed (downloaded from
>     https://repo.magento.com/archives/vertex/module-tax/vertex-module-tax-3.0.0.0.zip)**

the command:

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition m2
```

Comment: I had the same problem with vertex <b>during M2 upgrade from 2.2.7 to 2.3.0</b>. After the edit of `composer.json` you suggested, the command <b>composer update has completed successfully</b>.

Comment: This is not a resolution to the problem. Please see my comment under the accepted answer.

Comment: are you solve this issue?

Comment: @ManoM , in a day or two I was able to install magento 2.3. As far as I understand, the shasum was corrected and therefore the problem disappeared

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a problem on the Magento side.

The composer.json in the Composer cache expects that:

```
"dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://repo.magento.com/archives/vertex/module-tax/vertex-module-tax-3.0.0.0.zip",
      "reference": null,
      "shasum": "5301f7a4d294cabcab3ae83e31fe5386c076520c"
    },
```

I downloaded the "vertex-module-tax-3.0.0.0.zip".
The shasum is `dd5e23680878e70fdff546fa661822b100ab2bf3` which is different. That's why composer stops the download.

Comment: I would like to point out the obvious security vulnerability with this. The shasum is in place to confirm the packaged files are what you "expect". By updating the shasum to hide the error, you are acknowledging you could be using malicious files.

Answer (score 17):

Vertex is not a core magento module and can be remove in your `composer.json`.
Insert this under `require-dev{}`

```
"replace": {
        "vertex/module-tax": "*",
    },
```

Comment: "replace": {
        "vertex/module-tax": "*",
    }

Answer (score 2):

The genesis of the problem is in changing module files inside same public version.
This is bad practise and I feel shame for people, who made it happen.

Same problem occurred in the past for the `magento/composer` module.

To truly make it work, without changing of hashes (which is somewhat unacceptable, for professionals, because it may not work due to of the cached files, which may differ on multiple machines):

1. `rm -rf vendor/vertex`
2. `rm -rf ~/.cache/composer/files/vertex` or `rm -rf ~/.composer/cache/files/vertex` (depeneds on OS)
3. `composer update vertex/module-tax`

That will download new zip, with different checksum.

If you using multiserver infrastructure, you should clear that specific cache files on each of your machines.

Read more on the topic here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19283

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall composer. That was the solution for me on Mac.

Run:

```
brew reinstall composer
```